# Last name is first on a JR Pass voucher

Tags: trains, public-transport, japan, jr-passes

Recently I purchased a JR Pass, and the voucher came in the mail.  I am an American with a first, middle, and last name.  Suppose my name is Samuel Nathan Clemens, which shows up on my passport as:

> SAMUEL NATHAN CLEMENS

On the JR Pass voucher that came in the mail, it says:

> Mr CLEMENS SAMUEL NATHAN

Is this a problem?

**Edit**

Relating to phoog's comments, I eventually took another look at my passport, and lo and behold, the last name was first on the passport as well.  But one thing that was interesting was that they somewhat avoided the whole discussion by just putting the last name in one field and the first and middle name in another.

Comment: You seem not to have noticed that your passport also lists your family name before your given names.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should not be a problem. Conventionally, Japanese names are written with the surname first. They are applying the same convention to your name.

Comment: In addition, US passports actually show the family name before the given names.